# Using UPSERT PostgreSQL from Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I use "UPSERT" or "INSERT INTO likes (user_id,person_id) VALUES (32,64) ON CONFLICT (user_id,person_id) DO NOTHING" in PostgreSQL 9.5 on Rails 4.2?

Comment: I made a gem for Rails 5 if you have the opportunity to update: https://github.com/jesjos/active_record_upsert

Comment: Alternatively: I'd love a PR that enables Rails 4.2 support

Comment: Why don't you use Active Records `find_or_create_by`?

Comment: @Rocco Because it's not Atomic and I prefer the database to handle my data as much as possible.

Comment: @Jesper That looks really interesting. Too bad I use jRuby.

Comment: @user3384741 We use it with jruby where I work. Caveat is that you have to use a patched version of activerecord-jdbc: https://github.com/jensnockert/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/tree/activerecord-50

Comment: @user3384741 Another caveat: my gem currently only handles conflicts on the primary key

Comment: @Rocco: `find_or_create_by` will only return the record if it exists, it wont update/merge it. So it still requires two database calls after updating attributes and saving in that instance, whereas a true upsert is always one call.

Comment: find_or_create_by also doesn't handle race conditions.  Throw in threading(unicorn) or multi systems, and find_or_create doesn't cut it.  Perhaps it should be altered to use upsert.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `active_record_upsert` gem here: https://github.com/jesjos/active_record_upsert. This does the upsert, but obviously only on Postgres 9.5+.

Comment: This does not answer the question - he is looking for `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.  That gem only does `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.  Big difference!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating the SQL using the active records internals. You can use the `arel_attributes_with_values_for_create` to extract values for each active_record for the insert sql with the Rails attributes, something like:

```
INSERT_REGEX = /(INSERT INTO .* VALUES) (.*)/

def values_for(active_record)
  active_record.updated_at = Time.now if active_record.respond_to?(:updated_at)
  active_record.created_at ||= Time.now if active_record.respond_to?(:created_at)

  sql = active_record.class.arel_table.create_insert.tap do |insert_manager|
    insert_manager.insert(
      active_record.send(:arel_attributes_with_values_for_create, active_record.attribute_names.sort)
    )
  end.to_sql

  INSERT_REGEX.match(sql).captures[1]
end
```

Then you can add all the values into one big "values" string:

```
def values(active_records)
  active_records.map { |active_record| values_for(active_record) }.join(",")
end
```

For the insert part of the SQL you can use a similar code to the one used for the value extraction:

```
INSERT_REGEX = /(INSERT INTO .* VALUES) (.*)/

def insert_statement(active_record)
  sql = active_record.class.arel_table.create_insert.tap do |insert_manager|
    insert_manager.insert(
      active_record.send(:arel_attributes_with_values_for_create, active_record.attribute_names.sort)
    )
  end.to_sql
  INSERT_REGEX.match(sql).captures[0]
end
```

For the conflict part you can do the following:

```
def on_conflict_statement(conflict_fields)
  return ';' if conflict_fields.blank?

  "ON CONFLICT (#{conflict_fields.join(', ')}) DO NOTHING"
end
```

At the end just concatenate all of them together for execution:

```
def perform(active_records:, conflict_fields:)
  return if active_records.empty?

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    <<-SQL.squish
        #{insert_statement(active_records.first)}
        #{values(active_records)}
        #{on_conflict_statement(conflict_fields)}
    SQL
  )
end
```

You can check [here](https://gist.github.com/marcelorxaviers/9fc7ffeec007e497477cfc412de285bc) the final solution.

This is the output for me - using my **balance** active record model and removing the piece of code that executes the SQL(`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute...`):

```
> puts BatchCreate.perform(active_records: [balance], conflict_fields: [:bank_account_id, :date])
INSERT INTO "balances" ("amount", "created_at", "currency", "date", "id", "bank_account_id", "updated_at") VALUES (0, '2018-11-28 15:42:44.312954', 'MXN', '2018-11-28', 15169, 26300, '2018-11-28 16:05:07.465402') ON CONFLICT (bank_account_id, date) DO NOTHING
```